# Changing image of UIButton when touched

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I'm changing the image of my button by using a boolean like this, but I have a couple of problems:

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkedButtonOutl: UIButton!
var hasBeenTouched = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkedButtonOutl.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        checkedButtonOutl.addTarget(self, action: "click", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        checkedButtonOutl.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false

    }

    func click(){
        if hasBeenTouched == false{
        checkedButtonOutl.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        hasBeenTouched = true
        }else{
        checkedButtonOutl.setImage(checkedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        hasBeenTouched = false
```

Right after the view has loaded, you have to touch the button two times before it changes. Also, when the button is touched it highlights, which I don't want and I thought the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` function would take care of.

Any suggestions on how to fix these two problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first problem is caused by initialising "hasBeenTouched" to false, so the first time your `click` function executes it sets the unchecked image (again)

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, so I fixed that, then there's only the highlighting problem left, which should be an easy fix, or no?

Comment: @Paulw11 So I fixed the highlighting issue by adding an long press gesture recognizer, and let the image change when it ended. Primitive, but it works.

Comment: please edit the question with your fix. or answer yourself here and accept it as answer